# Define StructType as input datatype of a Function Spark-Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a Spark UDF in scala, I need to define a Function's input datatype

I have a schema variable with the StructType, mentioned the same below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val relationsSchema = StructType(
      Seq(
        StructField("relation", ArrayType(
          StructType(Seq(
            StructField("attribute", StringType, true),
            StructField("email", StringType, true),
            StructField("fname", StringType, true),
            StructField("lname", StringType, true)
            )
          ), true
        ), true)
      )
    )
```

I'm trying to write a Function like below

```
val relationsFunc: Array[Map[String,String]] => Array[String] = _.map(do something)
val relationUDF = udf(relationsFunc)

input.withColumn("relation",relationUDF(col("relation")))
```

above code throws below exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(relation)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<map<string,string>> type, however, '`relation`' is of array<struct<attribute:string,email:string,fname:string,lname:string>> type.;;
'Project [relation#89, UDF(relation#89) AS proc#273]
```

if I give the input type as

`val relationsFunc: StructType => Array[String] =`

I'm not able to implement the logic, as _.map gives me metadata, filed names, etc.

Please advice how to define relationsSchema as input datatype in the below function.

```
val relationsFunc: ? => Array[String] = _.map(somelogic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure under relation is a `Row`, so your function should have the following signature :

```
val relationsFunc: Array[Row] => Array[String]
```

then you can access your data either by position or by name, ie :

```
{r:Row => r.getAs[String]("email")}
```

Comment: This gave me a Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row; but instead of Array, I used Seq, which worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the mapping table in the documentation to determine the data type representations between Spark SQL and Scala: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/sql-reference.html#data-types

Your `relation` field is a Spark SQL complex type of type `StructType`, which is represented by Scala type `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` so this is the input type you should be using.

I used your code to create this complete working example that extracts `email` values:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val relationsSchema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField("relation", ArrayType(
      StructType(
        Seq(
          StructField("attribute", StringType, true),
          StructField("email", StringType, true),
          StructField("fname", StringType, true),
          StructField("lname", StringType, true)
        )
      ), true
    ), true)
  )
)

val data = Seq(
  Row("{'relation':[{'attribute':'1','email':'johnny@example.com','fname': 'Johnny','lname': 'Appleseed'}]}")
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  relationsSchema
)

val relationsFunc = (relation: Array[Row]) => relation.map(_.getAs[String]("email"))
val relationUdf = udf(relationsFunc)

df.withColumn("relation", relationUdf(col("relation")))
```